# trying to find a model that matches my erd

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to model some objects using JPA persistence and I'm having a hard time creating code that results in the database structure that represents the data I'm trying to capture.
[image]

I expect an example of the data to be

```
base
----------------
1|100|01/01/2015
2|125|01/01/2015
3|175|01/01/2015

types
----------------
1|1|trusted
2|2|trusted
3|3|trusted
4|1|unknown
5|2|unknown
6|3|unknown

units
----------------
1|4|200|alpha
2|4|145|beta
3|4|561|delta
4|4| 14|sigma
5|5|  8|alpha
6|5| 89|beta
```

The object definitions would be something like

```
@DiscriminatorColumn("type")
abstract class AbstractType {
  Long id;
  int baseRange;
  Date effectiveDate;
  Set<Unit> units;
}
@DiscriminatorValue("trusted")
class Trusted extends AbstractType {
}
@DiscriminatorValue("unknown")
class Unknown extends AbstractType {
}
class Unit {
   Long id;
   @ManyToOne
   AbstractType abstractType;
   int unitValue;
   String attributeValue;
}
```

So that an instantiated `Unknown` would be

```
Unknown: {
    id: 5,
    baseRange: 125,
    effectiveDate: '01/01/2015',
    units: [{
        id: 5
        unitValue: 8
        attributeValue: 'alpha'
    }, {
        id: 6
        unitValue: 89
        attributeValue: 'beta'
    }]
}
```

I know I've left off a lot of expected code here.  I'm just not certain how I should be going about creating the model.  I looked at `@Embedded` for the `base`, but I didn't want to include those values in the `types` table.  Am I on the right track?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer here has to do with how the middle object (`type`) is saved.  Basically, I need to create a custom implementation of the repository that overrides the `save()` method.

```
public Type save(Type type)
{
    LOGGER.debug("save() method called from CustomRepositoryImpl");
    Base base = baseRepository
            .findByBaseRangeAndEffectiveDate(type.getBaseRange(), type.getEffectiveDate());
    if (null != base)
    {
        LOGGER.debug("found existing base id {}", base.getId());
        type.setBase(base);
    }
    return repo.save(type);
}
```

The challenging part was this class had to be annotated with `@Transactional` so that it could access the `@PersistenceContext private EntityManager entityManager;`

Additionally, the `repo` in the code is an encapsulated Repository that I instantiate with the `init()` method (which Spring calls).

```
public void init()
{
    JpaEntityInformation<Type, Long> newEntityInfo =
            new JpaMetamodelEntityInformation<Type, Long>(Type.class, entityManager.getMetamodel());
    repo = new SimpleJpaRepository<Type, Long>(newEntityInfo , entityManager);
}
```

I would rather have done this through inheritance, but I couldn't figure out how to make that work.